# Can nodejs or phantomjs screenshot a js heavy web page neat and tidy?

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs

I have seen phantomjs can open, screen capture a normal web page and save it as image. Can phantomjs render js heavy web page looked exactly the same as on modern web browser?

Comment: I believe phantomjs should have the same output as Chrome (as long as you're not doing Flash and stuff)

Comment: Heavily depends on the page. PhantomJS is not up to date. The latest engine is more than two years old.